# Mysql Calculation and sorting of reservation day prices from different table

Tags: mysql, select

i am having trouble while trying to calculate reservation prices (based day range) from different table and order it with result. all results seems same. i tryed it with "group by" than its taking too much time if there is too much records. what is the best solution to do that? thank you.

Sql;

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `vehicles` (`id`, `title`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'Renault Symbol', 1),
(2, 'Renault Clio', 1),
(3, 'Hyundai i20', 1),
(4, 'Hyundai i10', 1),
(5, 'Hyundai Accent', 1),
(6, 'Volkswagen up!', 0),
(7, 'Volkswagen Polo', 1),
(8, 'Ford Fiesta', 1),
(9, 'Fiat Panda', 1),
(10, 'Fiat Tipo', 1);

CREATE TABLE `vehicles_prices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vehicle_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `vehicles_prices` (`id`, `vehicle_id`, `day`, `price`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2021-10-01', '111'),
(2, 1, '2021-10-02', '112'),
(3, 1, '2021-10-03', '113'),
(4, 1, '2021-10-04', '114'),
(5, 1, '2021-10-05', '115'),
(6, 1, '2021-10-06', '116'),
(7, 1, '2021-10-07', '117'),
(8, 1, '2021-10-08', '118'),
(9, 1, '2021-10-09', '119'),
(10, 1, '2021-10-10', '120'),
(11, 2, '2021-10-01', '121'),
(12, 2, '2021-10-02', '122'),
(13, 2, '2021-10-03', '123'),
(14, 2, '2021-10-04', '124'),
(15, 2, '2021-10-05', '125'),
(16, 2, '2021-10-06', '126'),
(17, 2, '2021-10-07', '127'),
(18, 2, '2021-10-08', '128'),
(19, 2, '2021-10-09', '129'),
(20, 2, '2021-10-10', '130'),
(21, 3, '2021-10-01', '131'),
(22, 3, '2021-10-02', '132'),
(23, 3, '2021-10-03', '133'),
(24, 3, '2021-10-04', '134'),
(25, 3, '2021-10-05', '135'),
(26, 3, '2021-10-06', '136'),
(27, 3, '2021-10-07', '137'),
(28, 3, '2021-10-08', '138'),
(29, 3, '2021-10-09', '139'),
(30, 3, '2021-10-10', '140'),
(31, 4, '2021-10-01', '100'),
(32, 4, '2021-10-02', '102'),
(33, 4, '2021-10-03', '103'),
(34, 4, '2021-10-04', '104'),
(35, 4, '2021-10-05', '105'),
(36, 4, '2021-10-06', '106'),
(37, 4, '2021-10-07', '107'),
(38, 4, '2021-10-08', '108'),
(39, 4, '2021-10-09', '109'),
(40, 4, '2021-10-10', '110'),
(41, 7, '2021-10-01', '201'),
(42, 7, '2021-10-02', '202'),
(43, 7, '2021-10-03', '203'),
(44, 7, '2021-10-04', '204'),
(45, 7, '2021-10-05', '205'),
(46, 7, '2021-10-06', '206'),
(47, 7, '2021-10-07', '207'),
(48, 7, '2021-10-08', '208'),
(49, 7, '2021-10-09', '209'),
(50, 7, '2021-10-10', '210'),
(51, 8, '2021-10-01', '301'),
(52, 8, '2021-10-02', '302'),
(53, 8, '2021-10-03', '303'),
(54, 8, '2021-10-04', '304'),
(55, 8, '2021-10-05', '305'),
(56, 8, '2021-10-06', '306'),
(57, 8, '2021-10-07', '307'),
(58, 8, '2021-10-08', '308'),
(59, 8, '2021-10-09', '309'),
(60, 8, '2021-10-10', '310'),
(61, 9, '2021-10-01', '80'),
(62, 9, '2021-10-02', '81'),
(63, 9, '2021-10-03', '82'),
(64, 9, '2021-10-04', '83'),
(65, 9, '2021-10-05', '84'),
(66, 9, '2021-10-06', '85'),
(67, 9, '2021-10-07', '86'),
(68, 9, '2021-10-08', '87'),
(69, 9, '2021-10-09', '88'),
(70, 9, '2021-10-10', '89'),
(71, 10, '2021-10-01', '91'),
(72, 10, '2021-10-02', '92'),
(73, 10, '2021-10-03', '93'),
(74, 10, '2021-10-04', '94'),
(75, 10, '2021-10-05', '95'),
(76, 10, '2021-10-06', '96'),
(77, 10, '2021-10-07', '97'),
(78, 10, '2021-10-08', '98'),
(79, 10, '2021-10-09', '99'),
(80, 10, '2021-10-10', '100');


ALTER TABLE `vehicles`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `vehicles_prices`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `vehicles`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=11;

ALTER TABLE `vehicles_prices`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=81;
COMMIT;
```

Query;

```
SELECT
  *, (SELECT SUM(`price`) FROM `vehicles_prices` WHERE `day` BETWEEN '2021-10-02 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-05 23:59:59') AS `price_total`
FROM
  `vehicles`
WHERE
  `status` = 1
ORDER BY `price_total` DESC
```

Result;

```
id title          status price_total
 1 Renault Symbol      1        4628
 2 Renault Clio        1        4628 
 3 Hyundai i20         1        4628
 4 Hyundai i10         1        4628
 5 Hyundai Accent      1        4628
 7 Volkswagen Polo     1        4628
 8 Ford Fiesta         1        4628
 9 Fiat Panda          1        4628
10 Fiat Tipo           1        4628
```

Testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce3475f/5

Comment: That's the desired result !?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry no. date range "2021-10-02 to 2021-10-05 so for (vehicles) ID of 1 result must be 454, ID of 2 494

Comment: Plaese update your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

this query seems working;

```
SELECT
  `v`.`id`, `v`.`title`, SUM(`vp`.`price`) AS 'price_total'
FROM
  `vehicles` v
    LEFT JOIN `vehicles_prices` vp ON `v`.`id` = `vp`.`vehicle_id`
WHERE
  `status` = 1 AND `vp`.`day` BETWEEN '2021-10-02' AND '2021-10-05'
GROUP BY
  `v`.`id`
ORDER BY `price_total` ASC
```

```
id  title   price_total 
9   Fiat Panda  330 
10  Fiat Tipo   374 
4   Hyundai    i10  414 
1   Renault Symbol  454 
2   Renault Clio    494 
3   Hyundai i20 534    
7   Volkswagen Polo 814 
8   Ford Fiesta 1214
```

best wishes

Comment: `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =` is the same as `JOIN x...`

Comment: @Strawberry ```SELECT
  `v`.`id`, `v`.`title`, SUM(`vp`.`price`) AS 'price_total'
FROM
  `vehicles` v
    LEFT JOIN `vehicles_prices` vp ON `v`.`id` = `vp`.`vehicle_id`  AND `vp`.`day` BETWEEN '2021-10-02' AND '2021-10-05'
WHERE
  `status` = 1
GROUP BY
  `v`.`id`
ORDER BY `price_total` ASC``` not worked correctly (first price_total return null) ... have you any idea?

Comment: What is your expected result? Should any of the title with `NULL` being returned? If yes, should it return as `0` (zero) instead?